# openpyxl read excel with filtered data

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

With `openpyxl`, I am reading an excel file which has some filters applied already.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('C:\Users\dsivaji\Downloads\testcases.xlsx')
ws = wb['TestCaseList']
print ws['B3'].value
```

My goal to loop through the content of the column 'B'.  With this I will be able to read the content of the cell 'B3'. If filters applied and in that case, I don't want to start from the initial cell.

i.e. whichever visible in the excel (after applying the filters) , those alone I want to fetch.

After searching in web for sometime, found that `ws.row_dimensions` can help with the `visible`  property, but still no luck.

```
>>> ws.row_dimensions[1]
<openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.RowDimension object at 0x03EF5B48>
>>> ws.row_dimensions[2]
<openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.RowDimension object at 0x03EF5B70>
>>> ws.row_dimensions[3].visible
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'RowDimension' object has no attribute 'visible'
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. The name of the attribute is `hidden`. If you replace `visible` in your code with `hidden`, it should work.

Comment: is there any way to do this with `read_only` mode. Read-only doesn't have these attributes. It gives `AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'row_dimensions'` error

Answer (score 0):

openpyxl is a library for the OOXML file format (.xlsx) and not a replacement for an application like Microsoft Excel. As such support for filters is limited to reading and writing their definitions but not applying them.